# CRUD in ruby on rails. Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, crud

Working through the "Ruby on rails 3 essential training" I'm encountering an issue with my routes and URL's.  I have created a sujects_controller with a 'list' action and a 'show' action.  Within my localhost, when I enter in: 
localhost:3000.subjects/list, I get an error, 'couldn't find Subject with id=list'
But, when I enter in:
localhost:3000.subjects.  I get the list that should have come up when entering the first URL.  Also, after entering this second URL, I have links for Show, Edit, and Delete.  When I hover my mouse over the link "Show", at the bottom of the page, the future output reads localhost.3000/subjects(3).  This link works. But, according to my instructors tutorials, it should read, localhost.3000/subjects/show/3.  For some reason my links and/or actions, aren't working appropriately and I'm not sure why since I'm following the instructions.

Here is my subjects_controller.rb file:

```
    class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

def index
    list 
    render('list')
end

# def index
#   show
#   render('show')
# end

def list 
    @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
    #@subjects = Subject.all 
end 

def show 
    @subjects = Subject.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @subjects = Subject.new
end

def create 
    @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])

    if @subject.save 

    redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else 

    render('new')
    end

end

    end
```

Here is my list.html and show.html file:

```
 <div class="subject list">
<h2>Subjects</h2>

<table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Visible</th>
        <th>Pages</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= subject.position %></td>
        <td><%= subject.name %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'yes' : 'no' %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
            <%= link_to("Edit", '#', :class => 'action edit') %>
            <%= link_to("Delete", '#', :class => 'action delete') %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Show.html

```
    <%= link_to("<< Back to list", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

    <div class="subject show">
        <h2>Show Subject</h2>

        <table summary="Subject detail view">
            <tr> 
                <th>Name</th>
                <td><%= @subject.name %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Position</th>
                <td><%= @subject.position %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Visible?</th>
                <td><%= @subject.visible ? 'true' : 'false' %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Created</th>
                <td><%= @subject.created_at %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Updated</th>
                <td><%= @subject.updated_at %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
```

And my config/routes.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root :to=>"demo#index"
      get 'demo/index'
      get 'demo/hello'
      get 'demo/other_hello'
      resources :subjects  
      get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#list'
      get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#show'
      get 'subjects/create' => 'subjects#create'
```

The instructor never shows his routes.rb file so I just started using the gets in order to get my actions to work.  The resources :subjects wasn't able to take care of everything so I used GET.  Also in my subjects_controller I def:index to render list.  If I don't do that nothing works at all. I'm obviously new to all of this but love learning about it and any information is appreciated.  I have looked at the rails routing from the guides but that hasn't helped me much.  Its more the concept/theory of why my links/actions aren't working that I'd be very interested to hear about.  Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify in routes

`resources :subjects`
It creates seven actions( index, new, create, create, show, edit, update, destroy)

When you call `localhost:3000/subjects` it ask routes where to go. And `index` action is called

`/subjects` `subjects#index` display a list of all subjects

And when you are saying `localhost:3000/subjects/list`
It expect `id` after `/subjects` as there are routes mapped to that

`localhost:3000/subjects/5` when you will call this it will call show method in controller asking for record with id 5 in database
`/subjects/:id` `subjects#show`

If you want to see all the routes, from console type
`rake routes`

And if you want to define extra method like `list` as below

`get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#list'`

and remove all other routes for `list` from routes file

And there are many more options to specify `routes` and to learn that this is your best friend

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Okay this is starting to make sense but I'm still a little confused. In my confiq/routes.rb file I have get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#list' followed by resources :subjects.  Now, from my server, if I enter localhost.3000/subjects/list everything works fine.  But when I hover my mouse over show it still doesn't say localhost.3000/subjects/show5. But instead localhost.3000/subjects/5.  How can I get the show action to show up in my URL. How must I route my routed.rb file to do so

Comment: I am not sure why it is happening but I think this line in your `routes.rb` `get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#show'` and remove this too
      `get 'subjects/create' => 'subjects#create'`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `routes.rb` file. When you specify `resources :subjects` you're adding many routes, one of which is `get 'subjects/:id' => 'subjects#show'`

Since routes take precedence depending on the order you write them (top to bottom) this is overwriting your `get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#list'` line.

You also have many other redundant routes that are being overwritten there.

```
  get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#list'
  get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#show'
```

subjects#show won't ever be called because the route calling subjects#list will take precedence

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help. I'm at work for a couple hours and then I'm going to get home and put these routes in order. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you first decleared

```
      resources :subjects
```

and then the other routes.

In your case the best way to add routes to a resource is the following:

```
resources :subjects do
    collection do
        get :list, to: :show
    end
end
```

This will generate:

```
# rake routes
list_subjects GET    /subjects/list(.:format)     subjects#show
     subjects GET    /subjects(.:format)          subjects#index
              POST   /subjects(.:format)          subjects#create
  new_subject GET    /subjects/new(.:format)      subjects#new
 edit_subject GET    /subjects/:id/edit(.:format) subjects#edit
      subject GET    /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#show
              PATCH  /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#update
              PUT    /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#update
              DELETE /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#destroy
```